# how to pass value from controller to jsp without model or model atrribute in spring?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

**how to pass value from controller to jsp  without model or model atrribute in spring?**

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/selectUser", method = RequestMethod.GET  )
   public String getTravelByUserId(@RequestParam("userId") Long theId) {


    System.out.println("AdminController.getTravelByUserId");
    // get travels from the service
    List<Travel> travelList=travelService.getTravelByUserId(theId);
    //add the user which authenticatedAdmin to the model



    return "Admin/travel-list";
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve? Why is using a model map or model attribute no solution for you?

Comment: I forgot deleting model attribute

Comment: can you return as json!

Comment: I know that but  i want to send extra information such as username, user id

Answer (score 1):

You can use the request Parameters like this :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/selectUser", method = RequestMethod.GET  )
    public String getTravelByUserId(@RequestParam("userId") Long theId, HttpServletRequest request){

    ....

    request.setAttribute("userName", varToSend);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> how to pass value from controller to jsp without model or model
>   atrribute in spring?

You can return an HTTP response with JSON inside it. Let's aasume that you want to return a User object as JSON, then you'll need something like this (assuming that your controller is `@RestController`):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/selectUser", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "application/json", produces="application/json")
public ResponseEntity<User> getTravelByUserId(@RequestParam("userId") Long theId) {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    User userToReturn = new User();
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(userToReturn, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

On Client side you'll need to handle that HTTP message using Javascript.